# akka (java) sender() method behaves strangely

Tags: java, akka, actor, sender

Any known cases where `TypedActor.getContext().sender()` does not behave as expected?

I know that in fire-and-forget mode, it defaults to `deadLetters`, however I am running into something different:

```
// inside MainActor

IPrintingActor printingActor = create(IPrintingActor.class, PrintingActor.class);
printingActor.blockingPrintln("foo");
```

where `create` above is simply a wrapper for the usual `typedActorOf` call

```
// inside PrintingActor
@Override
public boolean blockingPrintln(String string)
{
   System.out.println(TypedActor.context().sender() + " says " + string);
   return true;
}
```

The output is

> Actor[akka://MySystem/user/$b] says foo

however, this actor is actually the same as TypedActor.context().self().

Any reasons the sender() call would return the same as self()? Printing statements in the main actor print

> Actor[akka://MySystem/user/$a]

for the MainActor and

> Actor[akka://MySystem/user/$b]

for the PrintingActor. Within the PrintingActor, however, they are both printed as

> Actor[akka://MySystem/user/$b]

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: i'm not an expert in Akka since my background is from the erlang side but if i'm not mistaken you are calling directly the method of the class but not actually sending a message to the actor.  I think you should use the bang (!) operator to send messages to the actor

Comment: thanks for looking into this, however I am using typed actors. Thus what I am doing is actually a blocking message send

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/typed-actors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender of the message which signified the method invocation will always be a temporary actor generated by the “ask” pattern, e.g. `.../temp/$a`. The reason is that it is not an actor which receives the reply but some internal entity which then returns the reply value as the method invocation return value. Hence no matter how it is implemented, you will never see the ref of the actor enclosing the method’s call site as the sender.

On a side note: I cannot reproduce your findings (i.e. that the sender was `.../user/$a` or similar), but you also did not specify which version of Akka you are using.

Comment: You are correct, I recently realized that one of them was actually printed as Actor[akka://MySystem/temp/$b] and the other Actor[akka://MySystem/user/$b] (temp vs user). You were quicker in posting the reply though. Thanks!